# Show that volume of cone of height $h$ and base radius $a$ is equal to $\frac{\pi a^2h}{3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral, divergence-operator, stokes-theorem

How can I show that volume of cone of heigh $h$ and base radius $a$ is equal to $\frac{\pi a^2h}{3}$ using the following formula:

$$V=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \int x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z + y\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z + z \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Let $S$ be a cone:

$$
V=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \int_S x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z + y\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z + z \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y= \frac13\int_S \langle x,y,z\rangle.n \,\mathrm{d}S  
$$

I can't use the divergence theorem as I don't have the equation of the cone with me.

I clearly have parametrise the surface of cone so as to solve this surface integral, but I am unable to find a nice parametrisation.

Can we take $z=h$ and so $\mathrm{d}z=0$?

This does give me the desired result as follow but I don't know if this is logical.

Let $R:x^2+y^2=a^2$

$$
V=\frac13\cdot \int_S x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z + y\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z + z \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \int_R h \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{h}3\cdot \pi a^2
$$

But can we do this?

Comment: Of course you cannot set $z=h$, because then you're dealing with the surface of a disk at height $h$, not the surface of the cone. Why not parametrize the cone by rotating a line segment of slope $h/a$ around the $z$-axis?

Comment: Maybe try polar/cylindrical coordinates? Then if the vertex of the cone is at the origin, and the base is above, then the equation is $z = \frac{h}{a}r$ for the "bottom"/"sides" of the cone, and $z=h$ for the flat base (the "top").

Comment: Thank you so much guys